# Как получить количество реакций discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть команда голосование которая создаёт ембед и добавляет лайки и дизлайки. Мне нужно чтобы он подсчитал количество реакций лайк и дизлайк и сравнил

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions( view_audit_log = True )
async def vote(ctx, time:int, *, text=None):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
    emb = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Started vote",
        color=0xffffff
        ) #Embed
    emb.add_field(name='Vote for:', value=text,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Time:', value=time,inline=False)
    emb.set_footer(text=f'{ctx.message.author}', icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send('@everyone')
    mess = await ctx.send( embed = emb )
    await mess.add_reaction('')
    await mess.add_reaction('')
    print(f'[SUCCESS] Started vote for {text}')
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    print('vote ended')
    mess = await mess.channel.fetch_message(mess.id)
    emb = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Ended vote",
        color=0xffffff
        ) #Embed
    emb.add_field(name='Vote for:', value=text,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Time:', value=time,inline=False)
    if liked > disliked:
        emb.add_field(name='Vote successful',inline=False)
    elif liked < disliked:
        emb.add_field(name='Vote failed',inline=False)
    else:
        emb.add_field(name='Votes are same', value='Revote needed',inline=False)
    emb.set_footer(text=f'{ctx.message.author}', icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for reaction in mess.reactions:
    if reaction.emoji == '':
        liked = reaction.count
    elif reaction.emoji == '':
        disliked = reaction.count
```